# How can I convert The Touch of Death 2E module to run in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, conversion, battle-map, map-making

I am including the Ravenloft: Touch of Death module from AD&D 2e in my D&D 5e campaign as I have repurposed the Hexad. However, the maps from the quest are a mess, the NPCs are disposable, and the use of actual Egyptian gods don't fit modern D&D.

How can I run this in D&D 5e? Are there replacement maps I can use that someone's redrawn for a VTT for example? I use Owlbear Rodeo so any flat map image will work.

[image: original maps]

As you can see, the Egypian theme is heavy in the maps and to replace those gods I need new maps. Additionally, the angle of the maps make them unuseable for VTT.  I don't mind using old school maps, but they have to be a straight top down for it to work.

Comment: Remember that as a DM you can adapt the pantheon of your campaign setting. Moreover, Egyptian gods are listed as one possible option for a pantheon: see [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-b-gods-of-the-multiverse#TheEgyptianPantheon) and [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-b-gods-of-the-multiverse#EgyptianDeities) in the basic rules.

Comment: Are you mostly concerned about the visuals/maps, or also about the rules conversion? It sounds like you want answers to both, but I think only the visuals part is getting through.

Comment: I am mostly concerned with the maps.  Preferably a more secular map as my campaign A) doesn't take place IN Ravenloft. B) uses a much smaller than typical, in D&D, pantheon.  I can always add symbols but removing them is much harder.  
I'm just looking for anything that might already be out there.  I am not trying to commission anything.

Answer (score 1):

#### You should read Dread Domain Har'Akir from Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft.

I haven't read Touch of Death (ToD), but according to [drivethrurpg](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/17490/RA3-Touch-of-Death-2e) the whole adventure runs in Har'Akir, which luckily for you is one of the Domains of Ravenloft covered in Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft (VRGtR). In there you will find:

- A map with Settlements and Sites.
- Description of the 4 oasis, Muhar, Ousa's Pyramid, The Labyrinth, The Sands of Sute, City of the Dead and the The Bent Pyramid).
- The  portrait of the Mummy Lord Ankhtepot (who I guess is the awakening ancient evil of ToD)
- Eight ideas for adventures in that domain.
- The redesigned Egyptian gods now called Gods of Har'Akir

All this written around the plot of Ankhtepot trying to revive himself. Guessing again, it sounds like a rewriting of the original adventure.

Answer (score 0):

### You can draw them yourself, or sketch them live in the VTT

While I can't point you at anyone who published 2D versions of these maps, it is pretty easy to use a generic drawing program (or even specialized software like [Campaign Cartographer](https://www.profantasy.com/products/cc3.asp)), to draw these maps yourself and upload them as image backgrounds into your VTT.

You need not even do that. Most VTTs have drawing tools, that allow you to draw room outlines on the grid as you go along. We have been playing several campaigns like that using adventures from earlier editions, because they did not come with pre-made digital maps, and doing this was way faster and less hassle than setting everything up in advance buy creating, scanning, uploading and scaling maps, and not much slower than unhiding an existing map either during play. It also leaves more room for theatre-of-the mind descriptions than if everything is painted out and nothing is left to the imagination.

Think of it as the digital analogue of a real-life battlegrid with dry-erease marker, which has for us proven more flexible, faster and simpler for play than elaborate efforts to build versions of the dungeon from Dwarven Forge or painted Styrofoam or Lego walls.

Feel free to use different gods, if you have more fun with that. With more abstract maps there is no problem in doing so.  The Egyptian pantheon however is fully compatible with "modern" 5e D&D. It is listed in the PHB on page 297, and its gods and godesses are listed on page 299, including alignment, domains and symbols.

(Btw, I like these isometic maps -- they look very much like the [cut section drawings](https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/1013544/view/great-pyramid-of-giza-cutaway-view-illustration) of the original pyramids. It's a pity that they are not useful in a VTT).